# extract last section of data from file using linux command

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have the input file (myfile) as:

```
>> Vi 'x' found in file /data/152.916612:2,/proforma invoice.doc
>> Vi 'x' found in file /data/152.48152834/Bank T.T Copy 12 d3d.doc
>> Vi 'x' found in file /data/155071755/Bank T.T Copy.doc
>> Vi 'x' found in file /data/1521/Quotation Request.doc
>> Vi 'x' found in file /data/15.462/Quotation Request 2ds.doc
>> Vi 'y' found in file /data/15.22649962_test4/Quotation Request 33  zz (.doc
>> Vi 'x' found in file /data/15.226462_test6/Quotation Request.doc
```

and I need to extract all data after the words "found in file " to have this
output:

```
/data/152.18224487:2,S/proforma invoice.doc
/data/152.916612:2,/proforma invoice.doc
/data/152.48152834/Bank T.T Copy 12 d3d.doc
/data/155071755/Bank T.T Copy.doc
/data/1521/Quotation Request.doc
/data/15.462/Quotation Request 2ds.doc
/data/15.22649962_test4/Quotation Request 33  zz (.doc
/data/15.226462_test6/Quotation Request.doc
```

I'm using this

```
grep "" myfile  |   awk '{print $7" "$8" "$9" "$10}'
```

it works but not in all situations , i.e. if there are a lot of spaces, latest words are not returned.

Are there other better ways to have the same output ?

Comment: than you to put it to my attention, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st Solution:*** This should be easily done by `awk`.

```
awk '{sub(/.*found in file/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** OR more precisely with making it as a field separator itself :)

```
awk -F"found in file" '{print $2}'  Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** With `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*found in file\(.*\)/\1/' Input_file
```

***4th solution:*** Using `match` function of `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/found in file/){print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}' Input_file
```

***5th solution:*** Using `grep`'s `\K` option(tested with provided samples).

```
grep -Po "found in file \K.*" Input_file
```