# exclude data from latest / to the end of row

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have the input file (myfile) as:

```
/data/152.18224487:2,S/proforma invoice.doc
/data/152.916612:2,/proforma invoice.doc
/data/152.48152834/Bank T.T Copy 12 d3d.doc
/data/155071755/Bank T.T Copy.doc
/data/1521/Quotation Request.doc
/data/15.462/Quotation Request 2ds.doc
/data/15.22649962_test4/Quotation Request 33  zz (.doc
/data/15.226462_test6/Quotation Request.doc
```

and I need to exclude all data after latest "/" to the end of the row to have this output:

```
/data/152.18224487:2,S
/data/152.916612:2,
/data/152.48152834
/data/155071755
/data/1521
/data/15.462
/data/15.22649962_test4
/data/15.226462_test6
```

How can I do this from command line linux ?

This is a follow-up question related to [extract last section of data from file using linux command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602952/extract-last-section-of-data-from-file-using-linux-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/\/.*\//){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

Above will look from `/` to till last occurrence of `/` in case your Input_file can start other than `/` then try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/.*\//){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

Comment: it works ! Please can you help me to do the countrary too , i.e. from /data/1521/file.doc to file.doc ?

Comment: @gr68, sure I could help you, could you please be more clear in your question and I will edit code for you then, cheers.

Comment: thank you , I found solution # basename  /data/1521/file.doc

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sed 's:/[^/]*$::' < inputfile > outputfile
```

You stated in a comment elsewhere that you also need *only the rest* after the last slash, so here we go:

```
sed 's:^.*/::' < inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is combined with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602952/extract-last-section-of-data-from-file-using-linux-command) ,
ie. data:

```
>> Vi 'x' found in file /data/152.916612:2,/proforma invoice.doc
>> Vi 'x' found in file /data/152.48152834/Bank T.T Copy 12 d3d.doc
>> Vi 'x' found in file /data/155071755/Bank T.T Copy.doc
...
```

wwk:

```
$ awk '
(s=match($0,/found in file /)+RLENGTH) && (match(substr($0,s),/.*\//)) {
    print substr($0,s,RLENGTH-1)
}' file
```

Output:

```
/data/152.18224487:2,S
/data/152.916612:2,
/data/152.48152834
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F/ '{print "/"$1$2"/"$3}' file 

/data/152.18224487:2,S
/data/152.916612:2,
/data/152.48152834
/data/155071755
/data/1521
/data/15.462
/data/15.22649962_test4
/data/15.226462_test6
```